# Manifolds from fundamental pieces

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

From the classification of closed surfaces, it follows that any closed surface can be obtained by gluing discs and pants along their boundaries. I wonder whether a similar statement holds in higher dimensions.

> Let $n\geq 3$. Does there exist a finite collection $\mathcal{C}$ of $n$-manifolds with boundary such that any closed $n$-manifold can be obtained from manifolds of $\mathcal{C}$ by identifying connected components of their boundaries?

I think a negative answer is known, but I am looking for precise references.

**Edit:** If needed, you can consider that the manifolds here are smooth.

Comment: I think you want gluing along entire boundary components as in the 2d case. Otherwise for triangulated manifolds you can simply take balls. You should also specify the category of manifolds you are working with (TOP, PL, DIFF).

Comment: This is a very nice question. After going back and forth between "clearly true" and "clearly false" I settled on "clearly unclear" even in dimension 3. My guess is that this conjecture can be disproven by using non-Haken hyperbolic 3-dimensional manifolds of high Heegaard genus since in this case Scharlemann-Thompson width equals the genus.  http://math.ucsb.edu/~mgscharl/papers/thinpostn.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sure that the question has a (non trivial) known answer, but I am not able to remember any precise reference...